# Create image from the colorized terminal output

Tags: bash

This will output a black and white image:

```
git diff --staged  . | convert label:@- diff.png
```

but I want the color of the text (as the red & green  is useful).  I guess to configure the background color.

Comment: how do you install convert on Mac ?

Comment: Did you try with `--color` as in this stackoverflow question [Git diff output to file preserve coloring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9706676/2953889). @ankii - convert is from [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#macosx)

Comment: Yes, I have a diff which has colour when you print it via `cat`. But the png that it makes it black text only. not even with -channel RBGA